# I just want to run PHP in the command line in Windows. How to get started?

Tags: php, windows, command-line

In Linux, all I had to do was install PHP and boom, I'm ready to go and can execute PHP scripts via command line.

In Windows, is it the same? If I just download the binary and install it, then can I run command line PHP? And also, should I get the thread-safe or non-thread-safe version? I have neither IIS (or do I with Windows 7 Ultimate?) nor Apache. I just want command-line functionality!

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: aha! I think this might help:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php

Sorry in advance for not finding that earlier!

Comment: As a side note, yes, you have IIS on Win 7 Ultimate. You can install it following the instructions on this site: http://digitizor.com/2009/02/20/how-to-install-microsoft-iis-server-on-windows-7/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the same under Windows, you just need to make sure php.exe [is in your PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) (in order to use php.exe from any directory) and you need to use CTRL-Z+RETURN for EOF (CTRL-D under Unix):

sample session:

```
D:\dev\php>php
<?php
echo 'foo';
?>
^Z
foo
D:\dev\php>
```

Comment: When you start php, whatever you type goes to php and you need to "tell" when then input ends. That's what is (CTRL-Z then RETURN) for [you need to type that].